# I need help understanding this step in the given lemma.

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, inequality

[image]

In the proof of Lemma $2.4$, I have shown that $\omega(t)/t$ is a decreasing function but how does it follow that $\omega(2t) \le C \omega(t)$?

Comment: $\omega (t)$ is defined in the paper. Why not type it in your question, saving the people you want to help you the trouble of finding and parsing lemma 2.4 in your 60+ page paper?

Comment: @Paul Sorry, I am new here, and I thought it would be sufficient to mention only what lemma I am talking about since then someone would not need to go through the entire paper to find the definition of $\omega(t)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\omega(t) = 1/\log(e/2t), 0< t \le \frac12$$

$$\omega(2t) = 1/\log(e/4t)$$

Since $\frac{\omega(t)}{t}$ is decreasing.

$$\frac{\omega(2t)}{2t} \le \frac{\omega(t)}{t} $$

We have $$\omega(2t) \le 2 \omega(t)$$

Since $r$ is bounded, say $|r| \le M$, $|r(x)-r(y)| \le 2M$.

We have $Q=\min_{x,y \in \Omega} \omega(|x-y|)>0$,

Hence we have $$|r(x)-r(y)| \le \left( \frac{2M}{Q}\right) \omega(|x-y|)$$

Comment: Since r(.) is bounded, so the how this result is occur $|\ r(x)-r(y)| \le C \omega(x-y)$

Comment: i am using the definition this for the above result $r(.)= p(x)-p(\infty)$, s0 $|\ r(x)-r(y)| = |\ p(x)-p(\infty)-p(y)+p(\infty)|$ s0, it become $|\ r(x)-r(y)|=| p(x)-p(y)| $ then how this result is proved i am stuck here $\le C \omega(x-y)$

Comment: But then in the above equation as $ C=\frac { 2M} {Q}$.

Comment: After this i have tried to show that if $ x\in \ R^n\backslash{\bar\Omega} $, now be a partition of unity subordinate to this decomposition  $\overset{}{\phi_=\overset{*}{\phi_1}\bigcup}{\overset{*}{\phi_2}}\bigcup.................{\overset{*}{\phi_n}}$   equation(1),so when we write the equation one in summation form then $\phi= \sum_{k}{\overset{*}{\phi_k}}$   equation(2). Thus $\tilde{r}(x)=r(p_k){\phi}$ equation(3).Hence putting equation (2)in equation(3) we get$$\tilde{r}(x)=\sum_{k}r(p_k) \overset{*}{\phi_k}$$

Comment: Is this be correct

Comment: I am not familiar with partition of unity subordinate and hence can't comment. You might like to post a new [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions)

Comment: Thank you so much  Siong Thye Goh